# Magento 2: No options under store: configuration -> general -> general

Tags: magento2, configuration, language

best regard.

I am new in the word of Magento 2,i was made the installation of Magento 2.1 and 2.2 with PHP 7.0.x in XAMPP , then of right installation when i try to change the language at store->configuration->General->General  Magento not show the information in general(i can not see the tags for the configuration  how to a manual and diferents tutorials).

please how can i fix this problem

[image: Magento 2: No options under store: configuration -> general -> general]

thanks

Comment: This issue because not generate file in /pub/static file

Answer (score 0):

You try this,

Remove pub/static/* (not .htaccess)

```
<magento-root> rm -rf  pub/static/*
```

Then generate static-content:

```
 <magento-root> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 <magento-root> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
 <magento-root> php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Then, check it let me know if you have issue.

Answer (score 0):

I make a step by step:

- i delete `pub/static/*` Manually except `.htaccess`.
- i run the 3 line of commands :

1- `<magento-root> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

2- `<magento-root> php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

3- `<magento-root> php bin/magento cache:clean`

The commands run so right, but when i refresh the website_admin, the problem persist.

Note:in XAMPP with PHP 5.6.x i don't have this problem